# Error: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I have a custom object, `Spaces`:

```
#import "Spaces.h"


@implementation Spaces

@synthesize spaceName;
@synthesize spaceUsers;
@synthesize spaceIcon;
@synthesize spaceID;

@synthesize imageURLString;


- (void)dealloc
{
    [spaceName release];
    [spaceUsers release];
    [spaceIcon release];

    [imageURLString release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

My root view controller implements a `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and grabs from an `NSArray` of `Spaces`:

```
    [[cell spaceName] setText:aSpace.spaceName];
    [[cell spaceChatType] setText:@"People"];
    [[cell spaceActiveUsers] setText:aSpace.spaceUsers];
```

This works fine and I can click to go into the detail view and back to the list, but after maybe 5-6 clicks back and forth between the table view and detail view, I get an error at `[[cell spaceName] setText:aSpace.spaceName];` which is

> '-[__NSCFSet spaceName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6047b90'"

Please help! Any insight will be very appreciated!

UPDATE:

I'm still getting the same error but I've narrowed it down to the this:

-I'm creating a detail view controller on didSelectRowAtIndexPath...
-The detail view is being pushed to the viewcontroller and displays fine, I have a back button added as well.
-The detail view loads information and refreshes on a timer
-Pressing the back button goes back to the table list view

This is the problem my detail view is not being released from memory so the more I go back and forth between the views the more timers were going off simultaneously. I added a check to viewWillDisappear that stops the timer by setting a bool value.

I noticed that the detail view is not unloading...

From the RootViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //no longer on initial view
    isinit = NO;

    //hide keyboard
    [spacesSearch resignFirstResponder];

    if (spaces != nil && spaces.count > 0)
    {
        //set back button reference
        UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Spaces" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(returnSpacesList:)];  
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;

        [backButton release];

        DetailViewController *details = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil]; 

        //Grab Data from selected Space object and pass to DetailViewController
        Spaces *aSpace = nil;
        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
        {
            if ([self.filteredListContent count] == 0)
            {
                //self.lastSearchText
                NSLog(@"Create new space code!");
            }
            else
            {
                aSpace = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            aSpace = [spaces objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        }

        //set title and display
        self.navigationController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/",aSpace.spaceName];

        //pass data
        [details passedValue:aSpace.spaceID :aSpace.spaceName];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];

        [aSpace release];
        [details release];

    }
}
```

How can I force the detail view to be released from memory?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the rest of your cellForRow... method? It looks like your cells are going out of scope and the pointer now points to memory that isn't your cell (pointing to a __NSCFSet in your example error).

Comment: You probably need to post some more code to get good help. To me it looks like you might have a memory leak, and some of your objects have gotten deallocated, but it's hard to say from the information given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `[cell spaceName]` has been autoReleased. I cannot see how you have defined that, but take a look at that part of your code.
If you need more help, you need to provide more code.

Comment: memory leak causing autorelease, detail view deloc not being called when returning to the table view because I failed to release some array variables, therefore still in use.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your `aSpace = [spaces objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];`
 is not returning a Space object. Perhaps before you try and use it you test to make sure with something like `if ([aSpace class] == [Spaces class])`